# Push to array in nested immutable object

Tags: immutable.js

Please i want to have object like below from none existing group object.

```
{
  name: '',
  group: {
    [nameValue]: [1,2,3,4]

  }

}
```

I want to push an item to the `[nameValue]` provided it match the text. My code below

```
myObj.mergeDeep(myObj , {
  groups: {
    [newObject.get('key')]: newObject
  }
});
```

The code above update my `[newObject.get('key')]` as an object. My question is `[newObject.get('key')]` is of type array, how do i pls push to the array instead of object. I want to have  an array of items under `[newObject.get('key')]` instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `myObj` is an Immutable Map or similar, you can use `.updateIn()`. [docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn)

```
myObj = myObj.updateIn(
  [newObject.get('key')],
  List(),
  list => list.push(newObject)
);
```